# How do state machines deal with events that contain value(like floor number)?

Tags: uml, boost-msm

I am playing around with http://boost-experimental.github.io/msm-lite/tutorial/index.html (tag is for boost-msm because there is not tag for msm-lite but similar question applies) and I have a question wrt designing state machines with many possible inputs.

Imagine you are modelling elevator. Beside obvious states like moving, stopped, door_open, door_closed I wonder how to model button pressed(that is a number from -2 to 39) since it is not feasible to have that many events(42 just for every button pressed).

Comment: If you found an answer to your
question, please consider [accepting
it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419), and up-voting it. If you did not find a satisfactory answer to your question, please
leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use guard conditions on transitions. They look like `[currentFloor != requested floor]`. Perhaps a better way is to model events like `upper floor selected`, `lower floor selected`, `current floor selected`. That collapses 42 buttons into three categories rather neatly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you design a floor selection with 42 buttons you would probably not map them each to a single input, but make a matrix (nobody will put 42 buttons on top of each other, would one?). Then of course you would not model each row an column but only two so you can show the sequential polling of each row column. Maybe you could also use "intelligent" buttons today that have a microchip which sends some "I have been pressed" information a serial line. Or you introduce a [voice recognition](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjMwKjB7_XLAhUCgA8KHayuCdkQyCkIHzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DAvp9aUkM5g0&usg=AFQjCNEZ08-l4CvPKmvGQpSIJZjrVOVoXA&sig2=sfiElYqTxszE6dBt6KX1NQ).

Having listed those few examples, I tend to close this question as simply too broad.

Comment: your inability to understand simple specific question does not mean it is too broad. Elevator is an example of a common setup when modeling something with state machines.

Comment: Thanks for the compliments.